# How to fix PSpice

Tags: wine

I have downloaded the PSpice 9.1 student version and run it. When I run the Simulation option I got this blank window and an "Unable to start application 'pspicead.exe' " error.  And I set it to *Analysis* -> *Bias Point Detail*.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not all programs work with WINE (in fact a very large number don't).

Per the WIneHQ test results for PSpice (both full version and student version) (https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=779), there  are very poor ratings - Garbage means it doesn't work for its intended purpose, Bronze means there's a lot of issues.

Most of the time, this isn't anything you as an end user or us as the community can do to 'fix' the thing.  Usually it means it's just not compatible with Wine or Wine hasn't developed the requisite components to run the program completely.

You may need to run a Windows VM instead and put PSpice on that instead of trying to run it via WINE.